# Repeating a short sound very fast with CreateJS

Tags: createjs, soundjs

## Goal

I am trying to create a fast ticking sound in a Cordova app using Createjs.

The ticking sound speed changes based on user settings.  At the moment the timing is erratic

## Setup

I have an mp3 audio file of a single tick sound that is 50ms long.

A target speed of repetition could be as fast as 10 times per second.

## Question

How can I get the sound to play evenly and consistently at that speed?

## More Technical Detail

createjs.Ticker.timingMode = createjs.Ticker.RAF_SYNCHED;
createjs.Ticker.framerate = 30;

Cheers for any help

Comment: Is there a particular issue you are looking to solve, or are you just looking for recommendations?

Comment: Thanks @Lanny.  Probably a bit of recommendation seeking but the issue is the erratic rhythm of the ticks when trying to play a sound repeatedly very fast.  Do you think it's possible to play my sound every 100ms?  Even if I have a framerate of 60 (~17ms) and play it every 6th tick, it sounds pretty erratic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be pretty straightforward. I set up a quick fiddle to play a sound a specific amount of times per second. It seems pretty reliable, even when playing at 60fps.

https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/ghjejvq9/

The approach is to just check every `Ticker.tick` if the amount of time has passed since the last tick sound. The duration is derived by `1000/ticksPerSecond`.

```
// Every tick
var d = new Date().getTime();
if (d > lastTick + 1000/ticksPerSecond) {
  createjs.Sound.play("tick");
  lastTick = d;
}
```

Comment: I think I got a bit excited before testing.  Perhaps it is a Cordova thing... but I've implemented your code and am still getting the erratic timing.  One console error is popping up. Uncaught TypeError: e.setPlaybackResource is not a function.  I'm using createJS 1.0.0

Comment: I think we solved error in the latest version (the function was incorrectly deprecated) -- https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/commit/33b1303425da20770688455c46aab28c6dab4cdc. You could also use a faster tick for more accuracy (like using RAF). Any latency in your tick could definitely prevent it from playing reliably -- my demo does nothing else, so there is nothing to impact its performance.

Comment: Cordova could also be adding an inconsistent delay between your call, and the actual sound ... :(

Comment: Thanks Lanny.  I did a console.log of the tick delta and it seemed to be pretty close to your jsfiddle.  Not different enough to account for the large delays I'm hearing in the playback.  So I guess it must be a Cordova issue I'll have to work around somehow.